# Any tool to encrypt /decrypt file names in

Tags: ubuntu, encryption

Is there any tool which allows me to encrypt /decrypt file names in ubuntu?

e.g. I create a directory, all the file names there are encrypt.
When I mount it with a password, all the file names there will be decrypted.

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/).  Does just what I believe you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[ecryptfs](https://launchpad.net/ecryptfs) would be apt for your use if you just need to encrypt a directory. Other options would be [dm-crypt](http://www.saout.de/misc/dm-crypt/), [Luks](http://code.google.com/p/cryptsetup/), [truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) though they tend to work on whole filesystem (needs a block or loop device)

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory for installation instruction

Answer (score 0):

I needed such a tool but could not find a simple and secure option.
So I created a simple command line utility to encrypt and decrypt file names.

Here is the code:
https://github.com/RemyDeWolf/jumbler